"Details" view of my controller returns the 404 error
The "Details" view of my controller returns the 404 error.
public IActionResult MyArticle(long? id)
{
    if (id == null || _repo.GetArticleByID(id) == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var article = _repo.GetArticleByID(id);

    ViewBag.Name = article.Name.Replace(" ", "_");

    var description = article.Description;
    ViewBag.description = description.Replace("\n", "<br/>");

    List<Images> photos = _IMG_repo.GetImageByArticleID(id).OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();

    ViewData["Photo"] = photos;

    return View(article);
}

The action MyArticle is not even activated.

If I do not provide the id in the browser address:
https://localhost:7105/Articles/MyArticle/

the action 'MyArticle(long? id)' is activated!
So I provided a valid id hardcoded in its code:


public IActionResult MyArticle(long? id)
{
    __id = 70003;__

    if (id == null || _repo.GetArticleByID(id) == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var article = _repo.GetArticleByID(id);
    // ...
    // ...
}

var article loads normally with all the data from the database (including photo links).
Except that return View(article) returns nothing, blank page.

I deleted the view and had it rebuilt automatically, Razor view.
Nothing changes. Error 404

Right click on the view in the solution explorer --> Show in browser.
The view is displayed WITH all the data, without the photos (basic Razor view)

I replace the content of the Razor view with my code.
Right click on the view in the solution explorer --> Show in browser
The view is displayed WITH all the data, WITH the photos.

The normal call of the view is a link in a 'Card'


<div class="card h-100 mx-2 mt-3" style="width: 16rem;">
   <img src="@Url.Content("~")/Upload/@item.VendeurName/@item.Crec_Ref/Thumbnails/     
@item.FirstImage" class="card-img-top" alt="..." href="#" />
<div class="card-body">
<h6 class="card-title soussoustitre-ajout">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nom)</h6>
<p class="card-price title-addition">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PublicPrice) €</p>
<a href="/Articles/MyArticle/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)" class="stretched-link"></a>
</div>
</div>


I checked that the name of the action MyArticle was correctly associated with the view MyArticle

I tested with Firefox and Brave. Same result

I have a clone of the app (which I am developing in parallel, and in which I perform various tests), and this clone works!

I stopped and restarted the computer.


I don't understand anything at all.
I don't know where or how to look anymore.
Thanks

Why don't u try this way. Test data exist before display. The system will display nothing if no data return.
article _article = new article();

var res = _repo.GetArticleByID(id);

if(res != null)
{
  article  = res;
}

return View(_article );


It doesn't change anything.
The action MyArticle(long? id) isn't even read.

The solution is trivial.
I modified the route by omitting a parameter.
           pattern: "{controller=Articles}/{action=MyArticles}");
Instead of
           pattern: "{controller=Articles}/{action=MyArticles}/{id?}");
'MyArticles' is the page that calls my view 'Details'
I hope this can help someone.
